# Invoking mbunit Test Runner Programmatically

Tags: c#, mbunit

I am currently building a test suite using mbunit. So far so good, but instead of using the included Icarus GUI, I want to have my own test runner. Not knowing much about what to do, I go on Gallio's Google group and copied the code posted by a user:

http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-user/browse_thread/thread/afab404a14674cd2

And I got the following exception instead:

Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeException was unhandled
  Message=Could not resolve component for service type 'Gallio.Runner.Projects.ITestProjectManager' because there do not appear to be any components registered and enabled for that service type.
  Source=Gallio
  StackTrace:
       at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.RegistryServiceLocator.ResolveNonDisabledDescriptor(Type serviceType)
       at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.RegistryServiceLocator.ResolveImpl(Type serviceType)
       at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.RegistryServiceLocator.ResolveTService
       at Gallio.Runner.TestLauncher.RunWithRuntime()
       at Gallio.Runner.TestLauncher.Run()
       at Dundas.Dashboard.TestSystem.TestPrograms.Driver.RunTests() in C:\Users\edmondc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AutomatedTestSystem\TestPrograms\ImageComparisonTest\Driver.cs:line 49
       at Dundas.Dashboard.TestSystem.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\edmondc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AutomatedTestSystem\TestConsole\Program.cs:line 13
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

What am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use the [Gallio Loader](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=devel%3agallio_loader) which might be found somewhere in the installation directory of Gallio. The loader is provided as a couple of [C# source files](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/v3/src/SDK/Loader) that you need to include in your project. Its purpose is to ease the integration of Gallio in custom applications.

A simple usage is the following:

```
TestLauncher launcher = new TestLauncher();
launcher.AddFilePattern("MyTestAssembly.dll");
TestLauncherResult result = launcher.Run();
```

**EDIT**: For a more complex usage of the test launcher, have a look at the [Echo](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/trunk/v3/src/Extensions/Echo/Gallio.Echo/EchoProgram.cs) source code.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for - a simple test runner class that allows me to load assemblies on the fly. Thanks!